# solving random walk problems

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

In a election with two candidates, candidate A receives a total of a votes and candidate B receives a total of b votes with a > b. Assuming the votes are counted in a random order, what is probability that A will lead during the entire counting processes?

Comment: Great question! What have you tried?

Comment: What I think is it looks like a simple random walk problem where $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +... + X_i$ where $X_i$ is a binomial random variable p = q = $\frac{1}{2}$. But I have trouble translating this problem into mathematical expression

Comment: This is known as [Bertrand's ballot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).